# Не печатается текст после нажатия кнопки

Tags: javascript, frontend

```js
function buttonClick(button) {
  document.getEllementById('t1').innerHTML = "1";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="textbox" class="text" id="t1">
  <input type="textbox" class="text">
  <input type="button" value="1" class="but" onclick="buttonClick(this)">
  <input type="button" value="2" class="but">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `innerHTML` в `input` используйте свойство `value`.

**`innerHTML`** - `HTML` внутри выбранного элемента.

**`value`** - значение (внутри `input` и тп).

```js
function buttonClick(button) {
  document.getElementById("t1").value = "1";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="textbox" class="text" id="t1">
  <input type="textbox" class="text">
  <input type="button" value="1" class="but" onclick="buttonClick(this)">
  <input type="button" value="2" class="but">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function buttonClick() {
  document.getElementById('t1').value = "1";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="textbox" class="text" id="t1">
  <input type="textbox" class="text">
  <input type="button" value="1" class="but" onclick="buttonClick()">
  <input type="button" value="2" class="but">
</div>
```